# Find the change of coordinates matrices from $B$ to $C$ and from $C$ to $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Let $V$ be the set of all points on the plane $x − 2y − 3z = 0$. You need not verify that $V$ is a vector space. Both $B = \left\{\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 2\\ 1\\0\end{smallmatrix} \right), \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 3\\0\\1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)\right\}$ and $C = \left\{\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1\\-1\\1 \end{smallmatrix} \right), \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 5\\1\\1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)\right\}$ are bases for $V$. Find the change of coordinates matrices from $B$ to $C$ and from $C$ to $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Express vectors of  $B$ in terms of vectors of $C$ and vice-versa. The coefficients will give you the change of coordinates matrices.

Comment: The tow change of coordinated matrices, B to C and C to B, will be inverses. Use this as a quick check.

Comment: @user8795 I think I am doing it wrong because I am not getting an answer. I am taking the x-2y-3z and forming $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ -2\\-3 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = a$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 2 \\ 1\\0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ + b$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 3\\ 0\\1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$